# Can we install Amazon video app on external SD card?

Tags: video, amazon-appstore, video-streaming

I am an Amazon Prime user. The Amazon Video App allows us to download the video to the phone so that we can watch them without wifi connection. I have a Samsung S5 phone 16G version. When I download a movie, the amazon app size increases. I think that the app somehow hold the movie data within itself. Normally, I can only download 2 movies into my phone because I have many apps and the system itself talks space. May I know whether there is anyway to put the app on SD card?

Answer (score 1):

In July 2016 Amazon upgraded their Amazon Video app... now when downloading a video it prompts you if you want it saved to your SD card (if you have one installed).  -Settings- in this app also has an Internal/SD Card toggle switch where to save. The negative is any videos already saved to Internal memory have to be deleted and re-downloaded to the SD Card if that is where you want them.

This whole subject freaked me out a bit as I just bought 6 seasons of Game of Thrones only to think I could not put on my (newly purchased) SD Card...  My lucky day that this app upgrade just happened within about the past 30 days.  The Hi-Res download to a 80/20 mbps SD card is painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

Every app has a data folder under `/data/data` partition that only they themselves can access. Your Amazon app downloads the videos to that folder. What you see as increased size of *data* is the size of that folder.

Application itself, no matter where it is located, will keep downloading things to folder. If you want to switch this data folder's location to SDcard, then you can use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.link2sdplus) to do so.

Comment: Have you verified that the said Amazon app download videos into its data directory under /data/ and not under internal/external SD card, most likely in Android/data/PACKAGE/?

Comment: @Firelord For DRM reasons, I think SarpSTA is right (I haven't checked it, though). Compare with Google Books/Music/Video, same stuff. If data would be stored on external SD card, they'd risk people extract it using a card reader – so unless every download is encrypted, that's rather unlikely.